# How to get values of encoded json using php in ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
echo json_encode(array('out' => $out, 'total' => $total ));
```

Hi, I am getting a JSON data as below using the above PHP code.

```
var result = {"out":"[{\"tax\":\"SGST@9%\",\"percent\":7.75},{\"tax\":\"CGST@9%\",\"percent\":7.75},{\"tax\":\"SGST@2.5%\",\"percent\":3.11},{\"tax\":\"CGST@2.5%\",\"percent\":3.11}]","total":210}
```

I need to get the elements in a separate variable like below

```
var out = [{"tax":"SGST@9%","percent":7.75},{"tax":"CGST@9%","percent":7.75},{"tax":"SGST@2.5%","percent":3.11},{"tax":"CGST@2.5%","percent":3.11}];
var total = 210;
```

I tried so far with the below codes.

```
result = JSON.stringify(result);
result = result.replace(/\\/g, "");
var obj3 = JSON.parse(result);
alert(obj3[0]);
```

But i am not getting any output.

Comment: You don't need to do anything in js. Just access it like `result.tax`. This would work so long as your Ajax is setup to receive `JSON`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Ajax setup, add `JSON`

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

Then in your success function,

```
success: function(result) {
console.log(result.tax);//gives you the value for the tax key provided it's defined in the php response array
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `$out` is JSON to start with (so it ends up being double encoded), but it doesn't make sense for it to be JSON in the context.

You could just convert it to a PHP data structure before converting the wider array to JSON:

```
$out = json_decode($out, true);
$json = json_encode(array('out' => $out, 'total' => $total ));
echo "var result = $json;";
```

If you don't want to touch the PHP, you can work around that in JavaScript:

```
$out = json_decode($out, true);
$json = json_encode(array('out' => $out, 'total' => $total ));
echo "var result = $json;";
?>
var out_json = result.out;
var out = JSON.parse(out_json);
```